# postgresql indices - are they dense or sparse?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

What type of index - dense or sparse - does postgresql automatically generate?

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON Item (key);
```

Can I control this behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not create sparse indexes based on your CREATE INDEX statement above.

By sparse, I presume you mean:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Sparse_index

Relational databases support the traditional B-tree indexes.

However, technically, the GIN (aka inverted index) is a form of sparse index that is available in PostgreSQL.  See:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/gin-intro.html

So, based on your statement above, you can "control" this behavior so long as your key above is of a type that the GIN index can work with it.